# In Angular js how to use route(controller and method name)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
window.location.href ='@Url.Action("Redirect", "Dashboard")'
```

use this in js function but this is not working.

Comment: Give me a Solution

Comment: In angular docs you can get it easily how to do rouitng. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the 'routing' module for using routing in Angular.After importing you need to specify the path and the component in an object using array.
example:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path:'',
    pathMatch:'full',
    component:WeatherViewComponent
}];
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is for angular. He is asking for angularjs.

Comment: Yes, I was telling for angular only @SaimaHaji

Comment: ```This is working .                                                                                                             
        var url = '';
        url = '..controller/Method';
        window.location.href = url;```